# Get a dynamic column value in Activerecord Select statement

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a model named Product and I want to get the `id`, `name` and a dynamically calculated attribute value from ActiveRecord `SELECT` statement. `Product` model has `id`, `name`, `product_type` attributes.
Currently what I am trying is using an SQL like approach

```
Product.select("id, name, CASE WHEN product_type = 'AB' THEN 'xyz1' WHEN product_type = 'BC' THEN 'xyz2' END AS custom_value")
```

Which translates to the following Raw SQL

```
SELECT id, name, 
  CASE 
   WHEN product_type = 'AB' THEN 'xyz1'
   WHEN product_type = 'BC' THEN 'xyz2'
  END AS custom_value
FROM Product
```

but this approach does not return the column computed at runtime, it only returns the `id` and `name` columns for the `Product` record.

Comment: The "product_type" column isn´t visibile, but it´s there available for using it. Try `Product.select(...)[0].case`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "product_type" column isn't explicitly in the return value, but it´s there available for using it. If you execute `Product.select(...).first.case` you'll see its corresponding value.

If you want a different way to identify and access to it, you can use an alias:

```
Product.select("
  id,
  name,
  CASE
    WHEN product_type = 'AB' THEN 'xyz1'
    WHEN product_type = 'BC' THEN 'xyz2'
  END AS foo
").first.foo
# "xyz1"
```

Comment: the second way is working for me. First one says undefined method 'case' for Product.

Comment: Sorry, in that case as you're using an alias then it should be `custom_value`.